# matplotlib interactive plot with slices of image

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, bokeh, chaco

How would I make an interactive plot like the one displayed here?  I'd like to show an image with x and y slices of the image taken at a point that can be adjusted by clicking on the image.

[image: desired interactive plot where the image can be clicked to adjust the position of the slices]

I know this one was made in Chaco, but since Chaco isn't compatible with python3, just matplotlib or bokeh would be preferable.

Comment: This is definitely possible in matplotlib.  Have you tried?  I suggest starting by looking at http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html and  http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html.  Also see https://github.com/tacaswell/bubblegum/blob/master/bubblegum/backend/mpl/cross_section_2d.py for what you want, but you might need to extract it from a larger framework.

Comment: I hadn't tried it yet. I'm quite new to the event handling for matplotlib, but the cross_section_2d from bubblegum, which you suggested, is just what I was looking for. I guess cross section is a more common description than slice for a 2d image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tacaswells suggestion, I found that the cross_section_2d in bubblegum  was just what I was looking for.

First I installed bubblegum from github https://github.com/Nikea/bubblegum.git

Then the following sets up a cross_section image

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from bubblegum.backend.mpl.cross_section_2d import CrossSection
fig= plt.figure()
cs= CrossSection(fig)
img= np.random.rand(100,100)
cs.update_image(img)
plt.show()
```

Thanks!